# torsocks[7992]: Unable to resolve. Status reply: 4 (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:677) - Google Search

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspbian, tor, torsocks

I've installed tor on ubuntu 21.10
I've got

```
torsocks curl https://api.ipify.org?format=json
```

[image]
Tried port 9051

```
torsocks -P 9051 curl https://api.ipify.org?format=json
```

wit the same result.
Checked port 9150(which is for tor browser):

```
torsocks -P 9150 curl https://api.ipify.org?format=json
```

[image]

returns connection refused.

OS info:

```
uname -a:
Linux <username> 5.13.0-39-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 24 15:35:05 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Tor listens port 9050:

[image: tor listen port]

Tor service is enabled:
[image]

I've got the same error both on raspbian and rock pi x SBC

Comment: I have the same problem, maybe the reason for this is blocking Tor in your country (Russia?) ?

Answer (score 0):

This may sound a little strange. But have you tried to something like this:

1. Activate tor browser.
2. Choose new bridges.
3. Connect.
4. And only then try to `torsocks` or `torify`.

(works for me, if `TorPort 9150`)?